# TreeView - Default behaviour not working when edit

Tags: c#, treeview, default, undefined-behavior

When I edit a node in a TreeView and press the Escape key, the node is saved as if I pressed Enter.

Of course what I want is that it cancels the label-edit and the node doesn't change. I googled this and found out, that this should actually be the default behavior but it seems like it isn't in mine.

Nowhere in my code do I check for `Keys.Escape`, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Would be great if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't reproduce. Any other keyboard related events?? Any Before/AfterLabelEdit event code?

Comment: @Freggar I managed to find a solution to bypass the problem that the default behaviour doesn't work.

Comment: @TaW I managed to find a solution to bypass the problem that the default behaviour doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the default behaviour isn't applying for me but this is how I solved it now:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        ...
        ...
        case Keys.Escape:
            {
                if (mTreeView.LabelEdit)
                {
                    mCanceledEdit = true;
                    mTreeView.EndEdit(true);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void mTreeView_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, Crownwood.DotNetMagic.Controls.LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
   if(mCanceledEdit == true)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       mAppData.MainForm.UpdateData();
       mCanceledEdit = false;
       return;
   }
   ...
   ...
}
```

Explanation:
I wrote an event handler for when a key is pressed and when it's the Escape key and it happened during a label edit, I set my member variable mCanceledEdit to true and end the node editing.

Then in the AfterLabelEdit before doing anything else I check if mCanceledEdit is true, if so I cancel the node edit without saving the changes and set the variable back to false for further use.